# PDO select one id or all

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I'm trying to build a sorter with php and pdo, where I can show tasks for users.
I have several selects from which I can choose one value or all.

```
<select id="select_user">
    <option data-id="all">All</option>
    <option data-id="1">User 1</option>
    <option data-id="2">User 2</option>
    <option data-id="3">User 3</option>
    <option data-id="4">User 4</option>
</select>
```

Show tasks based on if they are finished or not.

```
<select id="task_done">
    <option data-id="all">All</option>
    <option data-id="1">Done</option>
    <option data-id="0">Not Done</option>
</select>
```

Show tasks based on if deadline has passed or not.

```
<select id="task_deadline">
    <option data-id="all">All</option>
    <option data-id="1">Passed</option>
    <option data-id="0">Not passed</option>
</select>
```

Via some Ajax I do the call to the php function that looks like this:

```
function getTasksSorter($userid, $done, $passed) {
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE user_id = :userid AND done = :done AND deadline_date = :passed');
    $stmt->execute(array('userid' => $userid,'done' => $done, 'passed' => $passed));
    $row = $stmt->fetchAll();

       foreach.. $row... build $html;

    }
    return $html;
}
```

Obviously this doesn't work if I choose All. I've tried to solve this but I can't figure it out. How do I modify the code to make the all choice work?

EDIT: Ok, I added a lot of more info since I wasn't clear enough when I first asked. I don't want to solve this with a pile of if statements, there has to be a better solution.

Comment: If I was doing this, I was just checking for the `$userid` and decide whether to put the `WHERE` condition and of course `$stmt->execute(array('userid' => $userid));` line with a simple if.

Comment: This won't do the trick in the long run since I want to add more values to sort for. Would end up with a lot of if statements.

Comment: I always create a query string for these type of situations based upon my conditions. Easy way :) I had several `if` statements in different projects, I don't think it's weird.

Comment: Per your updated question, try the query builder answer on [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13773381/php-mysql-select-query-where-wildcard/13773732#13773732).

Comment: Thanks a lot for that one webaware!

Answer (score 3):

Well your logic could depend upon providing a value for `$userid` like this.

```
function getTasksSorter($userid = null) {
    if(is_null($userid)){
        $stmt = $this->conn->query('SELECT * FROM tasks');
    } else {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE user_id = :userid');
        $stmt->execute(array('userid' => $userid));
    }

    $row = $stmt->fetchAll();

       foreach.. $row... build $html;

    }
    return $html;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough, this will not be a good solution if I want to add more values to sort for.

Comment: Well you can add as many options as you like but you will still be able to fetch all data by not providing `$userid`. Either way this is the best I can do with the data you provided.